# What's the most efficient method for filtering a dom tree based on properties of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I've been playing around with several options, including jQuery filter, and my own recursive descent functions, and I'm not impressed with my results so far.

I'm going to dive in and see how efficient I can make my code; I bet someone else has done this, though, and done a good job.

So, what's the most efficient way for me to search through a dom tree? Say, for example, that I want to find all of the elements which have a src property which matches (`/.*google.*/`)

Comment: jQuery selectors aren't efficient enough for you?  What about `querySelector`?

Comment: What's wrong with .filter? That's precisely what it's for.

Comment: css selectors will be very efficient

Comment: jQuery will automaticly use `querySelector` if it is possible for the browser to run that piece of code.

Comment: Be very careful what you call a property and an attribute. When using the selectors suggested in the current answers, you're selecting elements with said attributes, not said properties. The property just happens to match the value in this case.

Comment: Is this for some specific, practical purpose, or are you just playing around trying to get things to run faster?

Comment: @BenBarden I'm playing with a toy version of a much more complicated problem - making this toy run faster should inspire me to solve the more complicated issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this.

```
$("[src*='/google/']", "#rootnode")
```

or

```
$("#rootnode [src*='/google/']")
```

See this test case (looks like by stats the first selector is 14 times as fast as the second, with exactly the same selector)
http://jsperf.com/test-selectorfidd123

Want to know why? jQuery has to loop through each element for each element it can find if you use the second selector. If you use the first, jQuery will look foor the `root` node which it will use a highest node of the hyarchie. And will not loop through all the other `DIVS` cus it's not necesarry.

A few months ago I did some more tests. If you use selectors which are able to run within CSS. jQuery is able to use `querySelector` from the native library. But if you use special selectors like `:selected` or `:nth-child` then jQuery has to use Javascript to loop through these elements. At that case it is better do something like: (where jQuery will use `querySelector` for the first part and JS for the `.find`

```
$("#native").find(":selected"); is faster than $("#native :selected");
```

Information:
[Attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
[Selector API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: And it will be more efficient if you target specific elements instead of all. For example, `$('script[src*="google"]')`

Comment: Correct the best way is to give the selector a parent. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

I think more than 90% of browsers today support `document.querySelectorAll(..)` and `document.querySelector(..)` with native code. You should be able to use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[src*="/google/"]');
```

This should be faster than anything written from JavaScript code by itself.  jQuery should use this if it's available as well.

Comment: This isn't true, see [Why is getElementsByTagName() faster than querySelectorAll()?](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/). We can write faster selectors by using the various `getElement(s)By...` functions and checking attributes and classes manually, plus `querySelectorAll` doesn't return a live nodeList or behave the same across browsers. It is best avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by efficient. If you mean 'elegant', as in easy to read, then Niels is right. If you mean efficient in terms of speed, you're using jQuery wrong.

Yes, the other ways mentioned will work, but they are probably better ways. Maybe you only have a dozen elements on your page and thats fine. But what are you going to do when there's 100, or 1,000? Searching all those elements is very expensive.

Here's the question you should ask:

How are these elements being created? How could I mark the ones I'll need later when they're being created.